# running a java discord bot

Tags: java, maven, discord, bots

I need a little/big help to run [this application](https://github.com/Ectrian/discord-epgp-bot):

I follow the entire guide provided by creator without success

```
Error: Could not find or load main class discord-epgp-bot-master.src.main.java.com.epgpbot.transport.discord.DiscordBotLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: discord-epgp-bot-master.src.main.java.com.epgpbot.transport.discord.DiscordBotLauncher
```

So, im using MAVEN to make the environment and also compiling the proyect:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:discord-epgp-bot-master baneside$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.epgpbot:epgp-discord-bot >--------------------
[INFO] Building epgp-discord-bot 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ epgp-discord-bot ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ epgp-discord-bot ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.581 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-13T17:30:08-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:discord-epgp-bot-master baneside$
```

But, I don't know how to run it :(

When I used this command:

```
mvn exec:java src.main.java.com.epgpbot.transport.discord.DiscordBotLauncher config.json
```

the following error show up:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.epgpbot:epgp-discord-bot >--------------------
[INFO] Building epgp-discord-bot 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.739 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-13T17:32:03-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "src.main.java.com.epgpbot.transport.discord.DiscordBotLauncher". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Also, when I try to run the "clean install" .jar file this happens:

```
java -jar /Users/baneside/discord-epgp-bot-master/target/epgp-discord-bot-0.0.1.jar

Usage: epgpbot config.json
```

Any ideas?

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:target baneside$ java -jar epgp-discord-bot-0.0.1.jar config.json
[Config] Loading... (config.json)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy
    at com.epgpbot.transport.discord.DiscordBotLauncher.main(DiscordBotLauncher.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 1 more
MacBook-Pro-de-Luis:target baneside$
```

Comment: The pom.xml sets the scope for JDA to `system`, this means you also have to use the jar at the same location in your system. It looks like the author of that project does not provide a portable solution. Open an issue on the github repo.